# Remove numbers from a string with a letter in front

Tags: python

```
combined['Cabin'] = combined['Cabin'].map(lambda c : c[0])
```

I'm following a tutorial, except this line throws the error `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Anyway to fix this?

My column's data looks like
[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYHmw.png)

Thanks!

```
def process_cabin():

global combined

# replacing missing cabins with U (for Unknown)
combined.Cabin.fillna('U',inplace=True)

# mapping each Cabin value with the cabin letter
combined['Cabin'] = combined['Cabin'].map(lambda c : c[0])

# dummy encoding ...
cabin_dummies = pd.get_dummies(combined['Cabin'],prefix='Cabin')

combined = pd.concat([combined,cabin_dummies],axis=1)

combined.drop('Cabin',axis=1,inplace=True)

status('cabin')
```

`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-70714b711c6d> in <module>()
----> 1 process_cabin()

<ipython-input-151-d9bb11cabd2c> in process_cabin()
      7 
      8     # mapping each Cabin value with the cabin letter
----> 9     combined['Cabin'] = combined['Cabin'].map(lambda c : c[0])
     10 
     11 

C:\Users\Data.Steve-PC\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in map(self, arg, na_action)
   2014                                      index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
   2015         else:
-> 2016             mapped = map_f(values, arg)
   2017             return self._constructor(mapped,
   2018                                      index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

pandas\src\inference.pyx in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:58435)()

<ipython-input-151-d9bb11cabd2c> in <lambda>(c)
      7 
      8     # mapping each Cabin value with the cabin letter
----> 9     combined['Cabin'] = combined['Cabin'].map(lambda c : c[0])
     10 
     11 

TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm working on Kaggle's Titanic dataset. In the tutorial, http://ahmedbesbes.com/how-to-score-08134-in-titanic-kaggle-challenge.html, he strips the room number from the deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that your `X` isn't what you think it is. If it's a float, for example, 123.45:

`>>> 123.45['Y']`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
`File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
`TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: X is a column of numeric and non-numeric data concatenated. "C50", for example.

Comment: You know that, or you think that? What happens if you print X? Or please, as another commenter said, show us the complete code that produces the problem.

Comment: I've uploaded the block of code and the full error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your concern. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame({'Y': ["NAN", "C85", "NAN", "C123", "NAN"]})
print X

      Y
0   NAN
1   C85
2   NAN
3  C123
4   NAN

lambda_f = lambda c: c[0]
X['Y'] = map(lambda_f, X['Y'])
print X

   Y
0  N
1  C
2  N
3  C
4  N
```